# How Do You Get a USER ID Through a Ping?

Tags: python, discord.py

I Have a Command Where You Need to Ping/Mention Someone as a Required Arg, But How would you Get Their userid Through the Mention?

Example:

```
async def id(ctx, ping):
    ctx.send(f"{ping}, your user id is {the person metioned's id}")
```

Comment: By "ping" you mean a mention?

Comment: yes, sorry for not clarifying

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
async def id(ctx, ping: discord.Member = None): # Assuming that 'ping' is a user you are mentioning
    await ctx.send(f"{ping.mention}, your user id is {ping.id}")
```

This is assuming that the argument 'ping' is a [discord.Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#member)